# jQuery not able to retrieve placeholder attribute value?

Tags: jquery, forms, html, watermark

Is there a jQuery way for me to retrieve the placeholder attribute of a form input element?  I've tried the obvious:

```
alert($('form_input_element').attr('placeholder'));
```

but it returns undefined in both firefox and chrome for some reason!  **All other attributes are displayed fine with the above code**...  is this a bug in jQuery?  using the latest version.  Is there a workaround?

***UPDATE***: Ok, very surprisingly another jQuery plugin was actually REMOVING the placeholder attributes on all input elements...  That's why I was getting undefineds.

Comment: @at i don't think there is any bug in jquery , check your class name properly and as others said check for dot infront of class

Comment: I have highlighted my sentence where I state the above code works fine, this is not an issue of improperly selecting the input element.

Comment: @at can you post your complete html or create the same html in jsfiddle.net

Comment: I actually tried using jsfiddle.net for the first time right after I replied to you, AMAZING SERVICE!  But I solved this issue as shown in my update.  Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get it in a browser that doesn't yet support it?

Comment: @at I think you are trying to access your class or id from a variable "form_input_element" in that case you should have to use it like $(form_input_element). single quote or double quote will be there if it is "id" or "class" in that case add "#" or "." before name

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your selector may match more than one input, and the first one of your collection has no placeholder attribute defined like in this example

http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/rmN7J/

so be sure that your selector returns one input or all of your inputs selected have placeholder attribute defined

Comment: Thank you, makes sense that would be a common error.  But I solved it as indicated by my update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is `form_input_element` a class name? If so, you need a `.` in front of it. (ie `$(".form_input_element")`)

If it's an id, then you need the `#` in front of it. (ie `$("#form_input_element")`)

Remember that the string you pass to the jQuery object is virtually identical to a CSS selector, so it must be formatted as such. Currently, your selector is looking for an element named `form_input_element` which does not exist.

Comment: I should've been more clear, but the issue is not that...  I can query other attributes of the input element, so I know I'm selecting it properly.  It's just the placeholder element I guess is causing problems for jQuery.